# Internet explorer 11 Mouse.dll crash fix?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, internet-explorer-11

I am having crashes on IE 11 ( Windows 7 ) it is caused by Mouse.dll.

I know that because when i open my IE 11 and mouse is **out of the browser window** the browser works, as soon as I enter the mouse inside browser, it crashes.

When viewing **Windows logs -> Application** I am getting this:

```
Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 10.0.9200.17609, time stamp: 0x5671a062
*Faulting module name: Mouse.dll, version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x406b6ca9
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x00002f95
Faulting process id: 0xfc4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3746f8e671b40
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Mouse.dll*
```

So how to fix crashes?

Should I delete the Mouse.dll file?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What software does it belong to?  Who signed the dll?

Comment: Have no idea:( Buz i think this Developer: Gtek Technologies Ltd Software: GTCoach

Comment: Look at the properties of the file and update your question.  Please use full words. If you don’t want the file in question then uninstall GTCoach